# Need Descriptive architecture to develop file server in dot net

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp, sockets

I have to develop a file server service that transfer file form a specified location to its client.Client when starts, requests file to server for current date. Server transfer those file to client.

Now constrains are as

1.Application run in intranet.
2.Need to transfer multiple file at a single transaction.
3.File size may be in GB.
4.System runs in real time environment.So proper transaction and acknowledgment needed.
5.Application develop in .net.
5.More than one client can present.

Now please help to decide architecture and .net technology (WCF (Http binding) WCF (net tcp binding) ,Socket Programing ( i want to use WCF )) that i choose to develop file server.

and Please refer some sample application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF Streaming can help you over netTcpBinding, if you run your app in intranet. File Size, max clients and other options you can configure in app.config file of your WCF Service.

Check links below.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcffileserver.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/9803b85e-87aa-46c1-9c15-95c0b89eb2d5

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx